# How can I run the emberjs tests on a webserver like nginx/apache?

Tags: nginx, ember.js

I cloned the git repo and placed in the document root of my nginx install. But when I run `http://localhost/ember.js/tests/index.html?package=ember-runtime`, get the following error:

```
Uncaught The module 'handlebars' could not be found, http://localhost/ember.js/tests/minispade.js:39
Source:     
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost/ember.js/tests/qunit/qunit.js:832:4)
```

Is there anyway to run the tests without having the whole ruby infrastructure installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars isn't Ruby, it is a javascript library.  I'm not sure why you think that you need Ruby from the output you've posted here.

...

Looking at the docs, it looks like the tests need the rake-pipeline gem.  So yes, you'll need Ruby installed.  I'd recommend using RVM if you are on a Mac or Linux.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up installing ruby using RVM on debian.